# CQL cassandra joins and selecting multiple data from 2 different tables

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, nosql

Let's say I have two tables department and person and a column work_in from person table is same as the id column from department (like foreign key and primary key). Now what if I want the first_name, last_name from person table and full_department_name from department table. What would be the CQL to get such result using Equi join?

Answer (score 1):

A smell of relational modeling in there :). There are no joins in Cassandra. Hint: Keep it denormalized to suit the queries.

In Cassandra, the data model should suit the access pattern and its ok to duplicate the data while doing so. So we need not have a two table design joining each other but two table design to serve different query patterns.

Say for example

**Access pattern 1:** given a person_id find his/her details with department details. Create the following table to serve that use case

```
CREATE TABLE department_by_person (person_id int, first_name text, last_name text, dept_id int , PRIMARY KEY (person_id, dept_id));
```

Now a query with person_id will get all his details requested including department_id.

```
select * from department_by_person where person_id  = ?
```

**Access pattern 2:** given a dept_id find his/her details with person details. You can another table to serve this use case by partition key being dept_id

```
CREATE TABLE person_by_department (person_id int, first_name text, last_name text, dept_id int , PRIMARY KEY (dept_id, person_id));
```

Now a query with dept_id will get all his/her details requested including person_id. But remember additional coding is involved to keep these two tables in sync, which were just duplicated based no the access pattern.

```
select * from person_by_department where dept_id  = ?
```

Alternatively you could create a materialized view instead of second table and then Cassandra will keep the MV in sync with the table. In other words, no additional application work is necessary here to keep in sync.

```
create materialized view mv_person_by_department as 
select person_id, first_name, last_name, dept_id 
from department_by_person
where person_id is not null 
and dept_id is not null
primary key (dept_id, person_id);
```

Now a query with dept_id will get all his/her details requested including person_id.

```
select * from mv_person_by_department where dept_id  = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So to get such type of data I always need to create another table and insert the data (which I needed from given table) to it?

Comment: As an alternate, I provided you the materialized view option as well where you don't have to manage/code for another table. You need to start modeling according the query patterns. So design the table according to the queries it needs to solve.

Comment: Yes but the MV will only give me the firstname, lastname, dept_id from person table, whereas I want the whole department name which is in another table called department. for eg. dept_id is 'ET' so the full department name for such id is 'Education and Training'. I would want the the full name.

Comment: Exactly your current table design wouldn't work as it is. The table sample I provided above you could extend it to hold dept_name and other details of department within the same table alongside the details of that person. The MV will hold exactly the same data but the primary key changes to accommodate the other query pattern by dept_id.